# How can I get access_token from JSON data

Tags: node.js, json, api

I am trying to get `access_token` from a REST API call, able to get the whole JSON response, but unable to access the `access_token` or `refresh_token` to use them.

```
var token = JSON.stringify(body);
var accessToken = token.access_token
console.log(accessToken);
```

> 'accessToken' is undefined i.e. cannot get the value

Please suggest

Comment: can you add whats comming in the console.log and please console token as well

Comment: @Risabh in the console it displays undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not knowing what is exactly your `body` and therefore guessing that it is an OAuth response. `JSON.stringify` is for parsing already made JSON object to string (as it says on the tin), so it's wrong usage. You should use `JSON.parse`.

Comment: @Mostafa glad to help. Thanking works by checkmarking the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it might help someone:

```
var response = await apiCall.json(); // Random API query
var token = (JSON.parse(response)).access_token; //Parse the token from the response as Pavel suggested
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const accessToken = JSON.stringify(response?.data?.token)
console.log(accessToken);
```

it will help you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.